# Need an if statement that is not met to goto start of code

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to set some if-statements to ensure user inputs do not go out of ranges I have set if they do I want the if statement to return them to the beginning of the main code.

```java
String animal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In Animal Name"); // Asking for user to enter a animal
String fruit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In A Fruit Name"); // Asking user to enter a fruit
int days = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In How Many Days Between 1 And 10"));
// Above integer is asking the user to enter the amount of days.

// Below if statements are basically error checking to ensure the user stays between the
// range asked for when they are asked to enter in days between 1 and 10.

if (days <= 0) { // Ensures that negative numbers cannot be entered.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, Please enter a number between 1 and 10");
    return;
}
if (days >= 10) { // Ensures nothing over 10 can be entered.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, Please enter a number between 1 and 10");
    return;
}
```

If the if statement says that its an error it should go back to asking them to re enter the days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to allow code to restart a block of code, i.e. to go back to the beginning and try again, is to use the `continue` and `break` statements with a "forever" loop.

```
for (;;) { // loop forever
    // some code here
    if (failure condition 1) {
        // handle failure here
        continue; // go back and try again
    }
    if (failure condition 2) {
        // handle failure here
        continue; // go back and try again
    }
    // more code and failure condition checks here
    break; // unconditional exit loop, since all is ok
}
```

If "some code here" is itself inside a loop, but need to go back to beginning and try again, you can use a label for that:

```
TRYAGAIN: for (;;) { // loop forever
    // some code here
    for (some looping here) {
        // some code here
        try {
            if (failure condition) {
                // handle failure here
                continue TRYAGAIN; // go back and try again
            }
        } finally {
            // code here will execute, even if 'continue' is used
        }
    }
    // more code and failure condition checks here
    break; // unconditional exit loop, since all is ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `do-while` loop which will execute at least a single time, looping back every time if `days` does not fulfill the conditions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    do {
        //Your other code
        String animal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In Animal Name"); // Asking for user to enter a animal
        String fruit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In A Fruit Name"); // Asking user to enter a fruit

        int days = askForInput();

        if (days <= 0 || days >= 10) { // Ensures that negative numbers cannot be entered.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, Please enter a number between 1 and 10");
        }

    } while (days <= 0 || days >= 10);
}

//Pass whatever parameters you might need
public static int askForInput() {
    int days = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In How Many Days Between 1 And 10"));
    //Any other code you want
    return days;
}
```

I also extracted it to a method and this might be unnecessary, but it will allow you add more functionality if you need it.

You can also move `animal` or `fruit` outside the `do` if you do not want that question to be asked every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
String animal;
String fruit;
int days = 0;

animal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In Animal Name");
fruit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In A Fruit Name");

while(days <= 0 || days > 10) {
    days = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter In How Many Days Between 1 And 10"));

    if (days <= 0 || days > 10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, Please enter a number between 1 and 10");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to add a brief explanation to the code just to teach the OP.

Comment: Warning: If the initial value of `days` doesn't meet the loop condition (for whatever reason), the body of the loop will never run.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop

```
// Your user prompt for animal and fruit goes here

boolean exit = false;
while(!exit)
{
    // Your user prompt for days code goes here

    if (days <= 0 || days > 10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, Please enter a number between 1 and 10");
        exit = false; // This is not necessary but nice for readability's sake
    }
    else {
        exit = true;
    }
}
```